# Android: Initialize GoogleApiClient in a service

Tags: android, android-service, google-api-client

How should we initialize googleApiClient in a service as i need to call that service every 1 hour. As we initialize it, it should show a pop up to select the account and ui initialization doesnt happen in service. Is there any other way?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: why dont u initialize google api client in Application class ?

Comment: then access it in Service class

Comment: I need to aceess the data of google api client and periodically send the data to server and also send the data even if the app is killed.